# Implement mozilla text-align-last property with css?

Tags: html, css, mozilla

How can I implement -moz-text-align-last with css that can align to center last line?
I have paragraph that has justify text-align. I like to set last line align to center without mozilla property.

```
-moz-text-align-last: center;
```

Thank u for help.

Comment: because run with other browser

Answer (score 0):

Except mozila, you can try this for css code:

```
text-align-last: center;
```

For applying this funcitonality through JS, we can use this way:

```
function myFunction()
{
  document.getElementById("myDIV").style.textAlignLast = "center";
  document.getElementById("myDIV").style.MozTextAlignLast = "center"; // Code for Firefox
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I think they want it to work in all browsers, while this [doesn't work in Opera or Safari](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align-last)

Comment: Please try this js approch.

Comment: How would it work in JS if it doesn't work in CSS, if you're using JS to... change the CSS styles?

Comment: Please visit this link and see Browser Support section there: http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2014/02/25/improving-your-sites-visual-details-css3-text-align-last/

Answer (score 0):

Some of the browsers doesn't support text-align-last you can refer [here](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css/properties/text-align-last).